# Does com.android.providers.calendar remove deleted events or just flag them as deleted?

Tags: android, database, calendar, android-calendar

In Android KitKat, does `com.android.providers.calendar` remove deleted calendar **events** from the calendar storage databases, or does it just flag them as deleted?

If it does just flag them in the database, what does it write to the database to reflect the deletion?

I am primarily interested in how this pertains to local (non-synced) calendars, but technical responses regarding both local and synced calendars are welcome.

*If this question belongs on Android SE instead of here, **please** migrate it.  I decided to post it here because (1) the more technical audience here might actually be able to answer this question, and (2) Android SE will probably recognize that this is a programming-related question and migrate it to StackOverflow.*

Answer (score 1):

Event has a [`DELETED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.SyncColumns.html#DELETED) column and also a [`DIRTY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.SyncColumns.html#DIRTY) column.

As I experienced, `CalendarProvider` doesn't do any special thing with these columns and the work is up to you. So if you delete an event with a delete query it will be completely removed from database.

Calendar apps such as `Google Calendar` work in this way: If any kind of update or delete has occurred on an event, the `DIRTY` column is set to true. If the event is deleted by user, `DELETED` column is also set to true.

So when the `SyncAdapter` starts syncing, it finds the non-synced events whit `DIRTY` column and if the `DELETED` column is also true, it will completely delete that event from database after syncing.

Comment: Thanks Misagh.  Great explanation.  What about for local calendars stored on the Android device that are not synced?  I don't think `SyncAdapter` touches them (at least when there are no synced calendars on the device). For these calendars, are the deleted events ever actually deleted?

Comment: Your welcome. Yes, as I said, you can perform a delete query on every event whether it is local or not and it will be actually deleted from the database. In fact calendar apps don't perform delete query when the user deletes the event. They just set `DIRTY` and `DELETED` columns to true. `SyncAdapter` syncs these changes to server and then performs delete query to completely delete the deleted events.

Comment: Since `SyncAdapter` never syncs offline calendar changes to a server,  what actually deletes the events flagged as `DIRTY` or `DELETED`?

Comment: There is no need to set `DIRTY` and `DELETED` columns for offline calendars. These columns are actually in `CalendarSyncColumns`. You can simply delete any kind of event with: `context.getContentResolver().delete()`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the sources of [CalendarProvider2.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java/#3249).

As you can see, there are only two cases in which the event is actually deleted from the database:

1. It's been deleted by a sync adapter
2. It has an empty SYNC_ID, which means it has not been synced (yet).

If the event has been synced by a sync-adapter and it's deleted by a normal app, the event is always just flagged as *deleted* (By setting the `DELETED` column to `1`). This is necessary to inform the sync-adapter about the removal. If the event would be removed completely so that the sync-adapter can't find it, it would just assume the event has not been synced yet and restore it from the server.

Regarding local calendars: if the local calendar is not supported by a sync-adapter the event is deleted right away, because those events will always have an empty `SYNC_ID` field.

Note that as normal app should not try to modify the `DELETED` and `DIRTY` columns. Their values are set by the calendar provider and cleared by the sync-adapter.

### update to follow up with your comment

It's true that you can not modify single instances of a recurring event if it doesn't have a `SYNC_ID`. So in order to modify a single instance of a recurring event you need to assign a fake `SYNC_ID`. This is not required for non-recurring events.

If you delete such an event as a non-sync adapter app, the event might stay in our calendar database forever, just with a deleted flag set to 1.

To work around this, I see two options:

### The easy but "hacky" way

The easy way would be to pretend you're a sync adapter for the respective account. I've not seen any checks for this so far, so I think the calendar provider won't complain if you're not a sync adapter. However you need to ensure that you do that for local accounts (that have no real sync adapter) only, otherwise you'll break things.

### The clean way

For the clean way you need to distinguish several cases:

#### Delete an event that has an empty `SYNC_ID`

In this case you can just go ahead and delete it like before

#### Delete a non-recurring event that has a non-empty `SYNC_ID`

In this case you need to clear the `SYNC_ID` field first and delete the event in a second step (you can do that in a single transaction though). AFAIK, the calendar provider won't complain if you change the `SYNC_ID` as a non-sync adapter app. Though you should test that.

#### Delete an exception instance (as in "cancel" the instance) of a recurring event

You have two options.

1. Just set the event status to `Events.STATUS_CANCELED` this will keep the instance but it will "appear" as a deleted instance. This is how event instances are removed in Android in general.
2. Clear the `ORIGINAL_SYNC_ID` field, delete the instance and add an `EXDATE` to the master event.

#### Delete en entire recurring event (including all exceptions) that has a non-empty `SYNC_ID`

Here again your only option is to clear the `SYNC_ID` field and delete the event afterwards. In this case you may also have to delete all exceptions that have the same `ORIGINAL_SYNC_ID` (not sure if Android does that automatically). If there is more than one exception you'll have to clear the `ORIGINAL_SYNC_ID` first, otherwise they may not be deleted.

***Note***: I did not test any of these. My answer is purely based on my experience with the CalendarProvider and by looking into the sources at: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java

Comment: Great answer Marten!  Thanks!  From what I understand, there is a bug in Android that prevents the deletion or modification of individual events in a series for local calendars.  Thus, the standard practice appears to be to manually assign all events in a local calendar a UUID for the `SYNC_ID`.  But this then prevents events from actually getting deleted because their `SYNC_ID` is not null, and there is no sync-adapter to perform a deletion.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've just updated my answer to follow up with your comment.

Comment: Thanks so much Marten.  My brain is busy processing your update! ;-)